# 'absolute' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. In Sublime editor to work on lua love

Tags: sublimetext

I did every step that was required to run love2d on sublime text editor but its not working. Its giving me the folowing error after giving the path to love.

'absolute' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. [Finished in 47ms]

I thought there was a spelling mistake or something but nothing worked

Comment: Maintainer of Lua Love package here. This is weird, it looks like a bug. Do you changed any settings for Lua Love? What is path to your main.lua (is there some space maybe?). If not, would you like to report it [here](https://github.com/szensk/subllualove/issues) with some additional info, so I can look at it?